# Can we avoid scan in dynamodb

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I am new the noSQL data modelling so please excuse me if my question is trivial. One advise I found in dynamodb is always supply 'PartitionId' while querying otherwise, it will scan the whole table. But there could be cases where we need listing our items, for instance in case of ecom website, where we need to list our products on list page (with pagination).

How should we perform this listing by avoiding scan or using is efficiently?

Comment: Thats a very wide-range question. There are lot of ways of doing it. It all depends on your table design and efficient use of indexes. At first it might seem its pretty much like key value store only with single keys but there are many ways improving it. My suggestion read best practices like 10 times :) which I did
 https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/best-practices.html

Answer (score 16):

Basically, there are [three ways of reading data from DynamoDB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/SQLtoNoSQL.ReadData.html):

- `GetItem` – Retrieves a single item from a table. This is the most efficient way to read a single item, because it provides direct access to the physical location of the item.
- `Query` – Retrieves all of the items that have a specific partition key. Within those items, you can apply a condition to the sort key and retrieve only a subset of the data. Query provides quick, efficient access to the partitions where the data is stored.
- `Scan` – Retrieves all of the items in the specified table. (This operation should not be used with large tables, because it can consume large amounts of system resources.

And that's it. As you see, you should always prefer `GetItem` (`BatchGetItem`) to `Query`, and `Query` — to `Scan`.

You could use queries if you add a [sort key](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.Partitions.html#HowItWorks.Partitions.CompositeKey) to your data. I.e. you can use category as a hash key and product name as a sort key, so that the page showing items for a particular category could use querying by that category and product name. But that design is fragile, as you may need other keys for other pages, for example, you may need a vendor + price query if the user looks for a particular mobile phones. [Indexes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/SQLtoNoSQL.Indexes.html) can help here, but they come with their own tradeofs and [limitations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Limits.html#limits-secondary-indexes).

Moreover, filtering by arbitrary expressions is applied after the [query](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html#DDB-Query-request-FilterExpression) / [scan](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Scan.html#DDB-Scan-request-FilterExpression) operation completes but before you get the results, so you're charged for the whole query / scan. It's literally like filtering the data yourself in the application and not on the database side.

I would say that DynamoDB just is not intended for many kinds of workloads. Probably, it's not suited for your case too. Think of it as of a rich key-value (key to object) store, and not a "classic" RDBMS where indexes come at a lower cost and with less limitations and who provide developers rich querying capabilities.

There is a [good article](https://read.acloud.guru/why-amazon-dynamodb-isnt-for-everyone-and-how-to-decide-when-it-s-for-you-aefc52ea9476) describing potential issues with DynamoDB, take a look. It contains an awesome decision tree that guides you through the DynamoDB argumentation. I'm pasting it here, but please note, that the original author is [Forrest](https://forrestbrazeal.com/) [Brazeal](https://twitter.com/forrestbrazeal?lang=en).

[image]

[Another article](https://syslog.ravelin.com/you-probably-shouldnt-use-dynamodb-89143c1287ca) worth reading.

Finally, check out [this short answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47611747/750510) on SO about DynamoDB usecases and issues.

P.S. There is nothing criminal in doing scans (and I actually do them by schedule once per day in one of my projects), but that's an exceptional case and I regret about the decision to use DynamoDB in that case. It's not efficient in terms of speed, money, support and "dirtiness". I had to increase the capacity before the job and reduce it after, but that's another story…

Comment: +1 Great explanation, and this holds true not only to dynamodb but other nosql (documentdb) as well. If you need to show data from multiple shards (when partition key is not supplied), it always results into scan. Does it mean, while listing multiple items we should form a different strategy. For instance, blog is a great example to use nosql. All comments, like ect (belonging to a blog) can be stored together in a document (inside some nosql). But how to display a list of blogs (with only blog it and title)?